# How to get rid of spaces with CSS

Tags: php, magento, css

I have a Magento Multistore installation, 2 stores actually.

1st store uses a custom developed theme by a company.
Check specification tab:

2nd site, uses a theme we bought, but also uses EASYTABS, a free extension with no support.

In the product catalog the FIELD that renders this specification its exactly the same.

Maybe its a problem in a CSS or I dont know.  Can somebody please help me to fix this issue of the spaces to make it look as store number 1?

This seems to be the file that renders that tab.  I enabled path hints in Magento, maybe with this can you help me a little further

```
<?php
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('easy_tabs/custom/customtabid')){
    $method = 'get' . ucfirst(Mage::getStoreConfig('easy_tabs/custom/customtabid'));
    $content = nl2br($this->getProduct()->$method());
    if(!empty($content)){
        echo '<div class="product-specs">'.$content.'</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong? Can you provide a screenshot highlighting the differences and specify which one you think is correct?

Comment: if you check the specification tab in the first one it shows fine and the second one shows lots of spaces before the table and also within each row

Comment: There are **SO MANY** `<br>` tags in the `<a name="specs">` in the second store. Where did those come from?

Comment: You should take the screenshots like @nachito said as well as post browser information.  For me, both tables are broken with Firefox 10 alpha, and the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I checked all browsers and the second store shows all those spaces, I dont see the need really of screenshots, I am sure everyone sees the same result. Dont you? I even tried iexplore with the same result

Comment: I'm seeing multiple issues, but yes, I see the spaces.  Looks like the nl2br is creating the `<br/>` tags, so whatever content from `$this->getProduct()->$method()` has a lot of "\n" characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're allowed to put HTML markup in the Specification, so change this line:

```
$content = nl2br($this->getProduct()->$method());
```

to:

```
$content = $this->getProduct()->$method();
```

and you won't have all the extra `<br>` tags (spaces).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem in the CSS, but in the PHP code. If you do a view source, you'll see there is a 
 appended at the end of each line, even within the table. So you have something like: `<table><br><tr><br>....` and that's why there is very spaced at the begining. I think the reason is you have a filter somewhere which replaces new lines with `<br>` (this sort of thing is usually used to output normal text written by a person, so that it's spaced properly).

Comment: I enabled path hints in magento and it shows me that the file for that tab is: catalogproductcustom.phtml, in the edit I post you can see the code of that file

Comment: please check I enabled path hints on Magento, I also edited the question of the file that renders the specification tab

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not a CSS issue but it is a markup issue there is lot of <br> tags below and above the table header

Comment: please check I enabled path hints on Magento, I also edited the question of the file that renders the specification tab